# Is there a way to use Laravel's mutator on a non-existing column?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

The method below is not being called since the 'other_name' attribute does not exist as a column in the table. How can I get the method to be called even if the column does not exist?

```
public function setOtherNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['name'] = $value;
}
```

Comment: If you use the attributes, when saving, Laravel will try to save to a non-existing column. that will throw an error. Why do you need this attribute, since it will not get saved? Maybe there is a better way of handeling what you want to do

Comment: How about just add a `public_name` property to the model class?

Comment: protected $appends = ['other_name'];

    public function getOtherNameAttribute()
    {
            return 'other name';
    }

in your model instance you will get other_name field

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely possible.
I'm using the same strategy to convert plain text passwords to hashed passwords in the model

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

public function setPasswordAttribute ($value) {
    $this->password_hash = Hash::make($value);
}

public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->password_hash;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public function getOtherNameAttribute()
{
    // $anyValue is anything you can use a string, parameter or whatever else you want
    return $this->attributes['other_name'] = $anyValue;
}
```

And you can call this attr from everywhere like: `$objectName->other_name`

Comment: getOtherNameAttribute needs to return the value, not set the value

Comment: But it also can set a new value, You can open just open any Laravel project and try it yourself. ;)

Comment: I tried this. It works for columns that do exist but not for columns that don't exist which is what I am trying to do. Any ideas?

Comment: @VasoGamdelidze You can set values with it..., true, You can also water your plants with a spoon.

Comment: And what does `$objectName->other_name` return if your don't return anything in `public function getOtherNameAttribute()` ? And where is `$anyValue` defined?

Comment: sorry I forgot to write return in method :D. 

$anyValue -> means anything that you want. inside the function, I just wrote sudo code, which I think should be understandable for everybody.

@randy no I have tested, it just did not show up if you would dump the whole class, but if you try to dump($ObjectName->other_name), you would see a result

Comment: Still, You use an attribute, that will cause the `save()` function to fail, because the column does not exist. AND you use a getAttribute function to SET an attribute. The function does not do what the name says. That is considered bad practice.